# UV Editing not showing vertices on some objects but works well on other objects

Tags: modeling, uv, objects, uv-image-editor, color

getting started with blender and i'm trying to color an object using UV Editing but after going into Edit mode in UV Editing i can't find vertices unlike other objects. So if i press A then S  then 0 to scale to lowest in UV editing the whole selection just disappears but on other objects works fine i.e after selecting all objects and then S to scale and press 0 it scales to lowest but still shows a single vertex which i can move around any color i want and if i select any face on the main object and move in the UV window with G a new vertex appears which i can move to other colors. I am following an instruction from youtube to model low poly objects by imphenzia.

EDIT: (Added Photos and Desc)

How i expect the UV to look before scaling to 0 / single vertex (The Ground in mesh/road)
[image: How i expect the UV to look before scaling to 0 / single vertex]

but instead i get this result in my UV when i edit some other objects
As you can see there are no vertices on this one so if i scale no vertex appear again (The building in mesh)
[image: As you can see there are no vertices on this one so if i scale no vertex appear again]

Picture of my mesh in object mode - Solid
[image: Picture of my mesh in object mode - Solid]

Picture of my mesh in Object mode - Material Preview
[image: Picture of my mesh in Object mode - Material Preview]

Comment: hi please share a pic of your mesh in object mode

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have just edited the question with more picture.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else still has this problem;

[image]

**The answer is to turn off your Subdivision modifier's 'Display in Edit mode'- setting off**,
and then force the UV-Editor window to refresh.

-You can simply do the latter by going in & out of edit mode, or just intercacting with the mesh by selecting any of the geometry in edit mode.